# Include de menu para outras páginas

Tags: php, html, css

Fala galera, estou tentando aprender na raça php, estou desenvolvendo um Site caseiro e eu gostaria que o meu Menu ficasse fixo em todas as páginas deste meu site.

Este é o arquivo menu.php que no caso é o que quero utilizar em todas as outras páginas com include:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ThreePower</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
<body>       
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="redes/redes.php">Redes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fóruns</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Vivao</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Programação</a>
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jquery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Projetos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Scripts </a></li>
                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</body>

</head>
```

Este é o meu Style que está misturado com o código html de cima:

```css
<style type="text/css">

body {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100% 100px;
  height: 800px;
}

 
#nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 100px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    margin-left: 340px;
}

 

#nav ul {

    font: 16px arial, tahoma, verdana;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

 

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

}

 

#nav ul li a {
    color: #555;
    background: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 1px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    display: block;

}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #066;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#nav li:hover a {

    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #FFF;
}
#nav li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #222;
}
#textos{
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Agora na minha página de redes.php(por exemplo), que quero inserir eu coloquei somente o seguinte comando para teste:

```
<? php include "menu.php"; ?>
```

Porém Não funciona nada, eu até pensei que fosse as configurações do meu WAMP, fucei e achei uma opção do php chamada Include e ela estava desabilitada, então eu a habilitei e nada funcionou, as 2 pastas estão no mesmo lugar dentro de "WWW".
Para mim a Sintaxe está correta, alguma observação pessoal?
Aproveitando a deixa...
É viável eu salvar todas as minhas páginas de desenvolvimento com extensão php?
Tendo em vista que o mesmo consegue "ler" ou melhor dizendo, diferenciar códigos a partir de tags como 


e o próprio .
desde já agradeço, abraços.

Comment: `<? php` não pode ter espaço

Comment: "Não funciona" em que sentido?

Comment: Não funciona no sentido de Não realizar a função Include na página redes.php, o menu não é passado para esta página...

Comment: No código original está correto, com <?php include "menu.php"; ?>

Comment: tenta trocar "include" por "require"

Comment: Realizei a troca e mesmo assim persiste o mesmo erro.

Comment: Coloque o código completo do arquivo, redes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você disse "*estar aprendendo na raça*", esta resposta irá te ajudar.

Uma *include* deve conter apenas o código que você quer que ela contenha. Como no seu exemplo, a sua include pretende ser um menu `nav`, logo ela deve conter apenas o HTML do menu, e não uma página completa, com as tags `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` etc.

Como a *include* é basicamente apenas uma parte integrante da página, a própria página onde está a include é que deve conter os CSS, scripts e as tags principais da estrutura da página, e não na include.

No seu caso, a include deveria conter apenas:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="redes/redes.php">Redes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fóruns</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Vivao</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clube</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stack</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Programação</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jquery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Projetos</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> Scripts </a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Esse código será incluído (por isso o nome `include`) na *página-mãe* e será parte do HTML da página, sofrendo todos os efeitos do CSS e scripts que possam ter no código da página onde ela está incluída.